# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range Error

Tags: java, apache, maven

I am experiencing the a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range` error.

> ~/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin]$ **mvn -version**
>
> /home//jdk1.7.0_75//bin/java -Xdebug -classpath
>   /home//apache-maven-3.3.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
>   -Dclassworlds.conf=/home//apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/home//apache-maven-3.3.3 -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home//apache-maven-3.3.3/bin org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -version
>
> *java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>           at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser.loadGlob(ConfigurationParser.java:343)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:246)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.configure(Launcher.java:131)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)*

My current setup:

Maven 3.3.3

Redhat 5.6

Have tried installing:

JDK 1.7 and 1.8

I even tried switching Java version but that did not help.

Comment: What's in your pom file? Or `settings.xml`. It clearly fails on parsing path pattern.

Comment: My Understanding: mvn is failing even before reading the pom file. I did not do any changes to the settings.xml. I downloaded Maven and untar'd it